# Can't add on close event to modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

have a small problem, can't add event on modal close, was trying all ways of event for bootstrap modal, was trying name of modal from modal-name and from id - same, event not triggered on closing this modal. Can't understand where is a problem?
Button events - working.
was trying:

```
<script>
$("#AfterBuy").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
</script>
```

and

```
<script>
$("#zakaz").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
</script>
```

solved with event code

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','.modal[modal-name=zakaz]',function () {
```

```
<div class="modal actionmodal fade" id="AfterBuy" modal-name="zakaz" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <img src="<?php echo $cur_url; ?>img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="">
                <button type="button" OnClick="unknowntest();" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <?php $elem = getPageTitle('18'); ?>
                            <div class="modal-title <?php echo $elem['title_tr'] ?>"><?php echo $elem['title'] ?></div>
                            <div class="greyline1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                       <form>
                            <?php printPage('18'); ?>
                            <div class="col-md-12 zakaz-field">
                                
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                            
                                <div class="buttons mt-5">
                                    <?php $elem = getElement('zakaz_print'); ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $cur_url; ?>order-check" target="_blank" class="btn btn-dark <?php echo $elem['content_tr'] ?> printzakaz"><?php echo $elem['content'] ?></a>
                                    <?php $elem = getElement('zakaz_download'); ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $cur_url; ?>order-check?a=1" class="btn btn-dark downloadzakaz <?php echo $elem['content_tr'] ?>"><?php echo $elem['content'] ?></a>
                                    <?php $elem = getElement('zakaz_close'); ?>
                                   <button type="button" OnClick="unknowntest();" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-dark <?php echo $elem['content_tr'] ?>"><?php echo $elem['content'] ?></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                       </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
function unknowntest() {
alert("Modal will be closed.");
//document.cookie = "sended-check=0";
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are those `<script>` tags being placed on the page? If you are placing the script tags with the hidden event listeners **before** the modal, then it will not work since the element is not yet available in the DOM when the script tag is evaluated.

Comment: in the end of modal code - before last </div> for this modal, was trying after unknowntest() script, before it, instead of it

Comment: `<script>
function unknowntest() {
alert("Modal will be closed.");
//document.cookie = "sended-check=0";
}
</script>
<script>
$("#After-Buy").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
</script>
</div>`

Comment: If you runs  `$("#AfterBuy").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){alert("Hello World!");});` in the navigator console works?

Comment: Your modal ID is `AfterBuy` not `After-Buy`

Comment: yep, changed to AfterBuy - not helping

Comment: Yes, if i run `$("#AfterBuy").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){alert("Hello World!");});` in chrome console than closing modal - alert is working, with code inside - not working

Comment: code inserted before last </div>
`<script>
function unknowntest() {
alert("Modal will be closed.");
//document.cookie = "sended-check=0";
}
</script>
<script>
$("#AfterBuy").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
</script>
`

Comment: so in the end, in my situation, code for event on modal close will be 
`$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','.modal[modal-name=zakaz]',function () {`
id is not working any other code is not working, this one is working, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Solved with event code -

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal','.modal[modal-name=zakaz]',function () {
```

probably is wirking only in my situation