# How to add event listener to Modal close on BootStrap 5.2

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

Trying to capture the close event on modal, but couldn't get a response from

```
modalObj.addEventListener('hide.bs.model', function(event) { console.log("hide.bs.modal event") });
```

I was using BootStrap 5.2 and tested on both Firefox and Chrome on XAMPP (Windows 10). Also tried the solution from [Can't add on close event to modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69720279/cant-add-on-close-event-to-modal), and failed with error (perhaps due to different version?). The JS codes are collected from the BS doc:

```
<script>
const modalObj =document.getElementById('myModal');
modalObj.addEventListener('hide.bs.model', function(event) { console.log("hide.bs.modal event") });
modalObj.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function(event) { console.log("show.bs.modal event") });
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
  console.log("Got an uncaught error: ", event.error)
})
</script>
```

The event 'show.bs.modal' works. However, no response to the event 'hide.bs.model'. ( I also tried 'hidden.bs.model', same result). BTW, there was no error reported from the DOM.

---

EDIT:
The error was caused by typo in the code, as pointed out by @maniaq. Let me correct the full HTML below so people may find it useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Modal</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Modal Events</h3>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                 Modal Test
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
const modalObj =document.getElementById('myModal');
modalObj.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', function(event) { console.log("hide.bs.modal event") });
modalObj.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function(event) { console.log("show.bs.modal event") });
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
  console.log("Got an uncaught error: ", event.error)
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please correct model to modal

Comment: Oh, thanks! Let me edit the full code in the question, hope people can make a use of it.